# Using ObservableCollection and Binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know this question may sound similar to my last one but this is a different approach taking from others advice. Going a different route I'm trying to bind whats in a listview to a couple of textboxes. I am extremely new to WPF's and Not sure if I'm doing this right. I guess this a MVVP approach. Right now the program doesn't do much. There is one item in the listview but it is empty(No name, age, grade). I can see the item b/c it highlights when I try to select it on the listview. Any help is greatly appreciated.

There is class that makes a string name, int age ,int grade and has getter and setter methods. Name of class is called Camper(age, grade, name)

Class BindingCamper: making observablecollection

```
     public class Camper
 {
public Camper[] requests;
public int[] relationValues;
public String name;
private String school;
public int age;
public int grade;
private Boolean isGrouped = false;
private string group;


      public Camper(int a, int g, String n)
{
    requests = new Camper[4];
    relationValues = new int[4];
    name = n;
    this.age = a;
    this.grade = g;
}

public Camper(String n)
{
    this.requests = new Camper[4];
    this.relationValues = new int[4];
    this.name = n;
}

public Camper()
{

}

// Getter Methods
public string getName()
{
    return name.ToString();
}
public string getSchool()
{
    return this.school;
}
public int getAge()
{
    return this.age;
}
public int getGrade()
{
    return this.grade;
}
public int getRelationValue(int i)
{
    if (i < relationValues.Length)
    {
        return relationValues[i];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

---

```
class BindingCamper
{
    public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers { get; private set; }

    public BindingCamper()
    {
        Campers = new ObservableCollection<Camper>();

    }
```

Another class(page) :

```
public partial class CampersPage : Page
{
    MainWindow _parentForm;

    public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers { get; private set; }

    public CampersPage(MainWindow parent)
    {
        _parentForm = parent;
        InitializeComponent();

       // Campers = new ObservableCollection<Camper>();
        var bindMe = new BindingCamper();
        Camper CampMe = new Camper(3, 4, "Tony Lagarrigue");
        // CampMe.getName();
        bindMe.Campers.Add(CampMe);
        DataContext = bindMe;
```

XAML to bind everything. :

```
      <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,40" x:Name ="listViewCampers" Width="200" SelectionChanged="listViewCampers_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Campers}" DisplayMemberPath="name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="{x:Null}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>



                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="40" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Grade" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Grade}" Width="40" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Grid Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="209,12,0,0" Name="infoGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="134*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="154*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,24,0,0" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding name, ElementName=listViewCampers}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,46,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" AcceptsReturn="True" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,103,0,0" Name="txtAge" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

Comment: Please show us the `Camper` class

Comment: If you are new to data binding then read the [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)...

Answer (score 4):

You need to create public properties in your viewmodel to bind to.

You should never make `getSomething()` methods in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

For this code in your ListView declaration:

```
DisplayMemberPath="name"
```

you are using the field name instead of the property.  I don't think that databinding works against fields, even if they are public (to be honest, I have never understood why this is the case).

It looks like you are doing this in a few other spots, too--make sure you are binding to the property, and make sure the name is correct (it is case sensitve).

**Edit**: as SLaks noted (I didn't notice this until he pointed it out), you are using methods as properties.  I think they need to be actual .Net properties with getters, e.g.:

```
public string Name
{
  get { return _name; }
}
```

Comment: You just answered me a question that was bugging me (and my code) for hours! Just adding { get; set; } to the >public string Name< in my class did the trick to make them visible as DisplayMemberPath in the ListView